# create-react-app and npm install webpack error : maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, create-react-app

Both `create-react-app` and `npm install webpack`(webpack is failing. Other packages installation worked) give "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error. Tried "`npm cache clean --force`", deleted package-lock, did reinstall on npm (`npm install`), `npm rebuild`, upgrade node and npm to recent stable versions (Node:8.12.0 & NPM:6.4.1 ). Inspite of all that error still exists.

`create-react-app demo-app` gives below error

```
Creating a new React app in D:\Projects\demo-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mkatti\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-08T07_21_50
_853Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts
 has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting demo-app / from D:\Projects
Done.
```

`npm install webpack --save-dev` gives below error

```
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ because the
host is inaccessible -- are you offline?
npm WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due
to a request error during revalidation.
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mkatti\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-08T07_28_07
_840Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you sure you have internet access for download more than certain size ?

Comment: Maybe try disabling "Windows Defender - Controlled Folder Access"? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48395826/1248811

Comment: @ViswanathLekshmanan, yes have sufficient internet access.

Comment: @Atav32, disabling "Windows Defender" did not work.

Comment: Do you have any proxy/settings in your configuration (.npmrc)?

Comment: have you solve the issue? I'm getting same error. I've tried whatever you've mention in question.